# Internet Explorer missing POST data in form.submit() request

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer, post

In IE11, using the normal form.submit() JS function, no POST variables are being submitted to the server. Dev console shows that POST Parameters are empty.

I'm using jQuery to fire an event when `.form-file-download` is clicked:

```
$(".form-file-download").on("click", 
                        ".download-file",
                        function (){
                            $(this).parent().submit();
                        });
```

This is the form being submitted:

```
<form class="form-file-download" action="/reqHandling/file.handler.php" method="post">
    <input name="file" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="download">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download download-file"></i>
</form>
```

The form data isn't manipulated by JS. I already tried un-hiding the inputs.

The submit function gets executed and sends a POST request to file.handler.php (as expected), but no parameters are being sent.

Firefox, Chrome and Edge do send the form data. Any idea what's wrong? Let me know if more details are needed!

Comment: Have you looked at the network inspector in IE's Developer tools to see what if anything is actually sent?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by saying Dev console shows that POST Parameters are empty. The request is a POST request to the right URL, headers are fine, but no POST data...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that!   Perhaps try renaming `action` as `theform.action` could be ambiguous between the element and attribute of the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the parameters get submitted in IE11:

https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/ug429jfd/1/

The IE dev tools just don't show as 'parameters' for POST requests, but as request text.

```
(ignore code for jsfiddle link)
```

Comment: I solved the problem a while ago... I think it was due to a JS manipulating all form elements onLoad. IE then wasn't able to send current values of the (still valid) form.